# Changing the image source in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, react-props

I am getting an error, 'Attempted to assign to readonly property'. I am not sure how to decipher this error message and I feel like my logic looks ok. I am not quite sure where to look.

container component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import { Image } from './Image.js'
import { Button } from './Button.js'

const images = ['https://uploads3.wikiart.org/images/wladyslaw-strzeminski/cover-for-a-book-by-julian-przybo-z-ponad-1930.jpg!Large.jpg',
'https://uploads6.wikiart.org/images/pablo-picasso/girl-on-the-ball-1905.jpg!Large.jpg',
 'https://uploads8.wikiart.org/images/salvador-dali/et-post-buccellam-introivit-in-eum-satanas-psalms-40-10-1964.jpg']

class Game extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      currentImg: 0
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick(){
    const current = this.state.currentImg; <--------- error points to this
    const next = ++current % images.length;
    this.setState({
      currentImg: next
    })
  }

  render(){
    let src = this.state.currentImg;
    return(
      <div>
        <Image src={images[src]} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

presentational components:
Button:

```
import React from 'react';

export const Button = (props) => {
    return <button onClick={props.onClick}></button>
}
```

Image:

```
import React from 'react';

  export const Image = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="flex-main-item">
          <img className="mainImage" src={props.src} /> 
        </div>
       )
  }
```

Comment: I think it's because you are using `const` to assign the `current` variable value. If the `current` value is going to change, it should be declared with `var` or `let` otherwise it's assumed that the value will be constant.

Comment: Yup, thats it. just too damn simple lol. thanks so much, I appreciate it.